# Simplest "tidy" way to assign a value to a specific dataframe cell using R dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

If I want to change the value of a specific cell in a dataframe with rownames, I can do it in a very intuitive manner by referencing the 2D coordinate of the cell `[rowname, colname]`. If I use a tidy dataframe that does not have rownames, the only way I can figure out how to do it is kind of ugly and unintuitive.

Is there a better way?

```r
library(tidyverse)

### Create DataFrame
df = data.frame(
  A=paste0('a', 1:3),
  B=paste0('b', 1:3),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df
#>    A  B
#> 1 a1 b1
#> 2 a2 b2
#> 3 a3 b3

### Copy to DataFrame with Rownames
df_rn = df %>% column_to_rownames('A')
df_rn
#>     B
#> a1 b1
#> a2 b2
#> a3 b3

### Mutate indexing rownames
df_rn['a2', 'B'] = "new"
df_rn
#>      B
#> a1  b1
#> a2 new
#> a3  b3

### Mutate using tidy methods
df %>%
  mutate(B = ifelse(A=='a2', 'new', B))
#>    A   B
#> 1 a1  b1
#> 2 a2 new
#> 3 a3  b3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### EDIT:

Incidentally, in SQL it is still fairly intuitive:

```
update df set B="new" where A=="a1"
```

### EDIT 2

Proposal:

```
df %>%
  set_where(A=='a2', B='new') %>%
  set_where(A %in% c('a1', 'a3'), B=c('other', 'value'))
```

or

```
df %>%
  update(
    list(A='a2', B='new'), 
    list(A='a1', B='other)
    )
```

Comment: Not posting as an answer since this isn't dplyr, but fwiw if you convert to data.table with `library(data.table); setDT(df)` this is quite easy. You can do `df[A == 'a2', B := 'new']` and your original `df` is updated.

Comment: `dplyr::recode` seems similar to what you're asking about. No need to be rude to folks who are trying to help you out

Comment: @camille -- can you please show me an example of using `dplyr::recode` on a conditional basis to accomplish the task? I hear you about the rudeness. It could be misplaced. The initial flurry of distracting activity on this question by one user, on top of multiple drive-by downvotes really bothered me.

Comment: ```library(magrittr); df[df$A=="a2",] %<>% mutate(B = 'new')```

Comment: @M-- Interesting approach. Does use `tidyverse`. It could be the start of a chain of operations, but could not be elsewhere. I believe it does provide a partial solution.

Comment: Actually I think `recode` isn't quite right because you're looking between variables. If this is something you need to do repeatedly or with really complicated conditions, might be worth writing a tidyeval function. But honestly the `ifelse` call you have seems fine and is how I often setup tasks like this

Comment: @camille It does totally work, and it's what I use, but is wordy and I feel indirect. In terms of tidy operations being SQL-like, I would like to see a purpose-built operation if one does not already exist.

Comment: `case_when` inside a mutate statement is pretty tidy for me, in fact I think this is its bigger use case. Your proposals can be translated to this (sorry, is a comment and I needed to stick it all in a oneliner) `df %>% mutate(B = case_when(A == 'a2' ~ 'new', A == 'a1' ~ 'other', ..., TRUE ~ NA_character)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code chunk either without any package;

```
df[which(df$A=="a2"),2] <- "new"
```

Comment: That's not tidy, and cannot be chained. The question specifically says to use `dplyr`.